# set.record not updating existing values in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I have the following. I can seen via firebug that it is posting the loaded version of the record and not the updated. However when i view the info of form.getValues(); it contains the correct values.

```
  // controller  
var form = Ext.getCmp('partForm');
    var record = form.getRecord();
    var values = form.getValues();
    record.set(values);
    record.save();
```

Answer (score 1):

**From Docs:**  [**http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic**](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/source/Basic.html#Ext-form-Basic-method-setValues)

**record.set :**
`Sets the given field to the given value, marks the instance as dirty`
`set( String/Object fieldName, Object value )`

**form.setValues :**
`Set values for fields in this form in bulk.`
`setValues( Object/Object[] values ) : Ext.form.Basic`

**Try Replacing**

```
    record.set(values);
```

**With**

```
    form.setValues(values);
```

Comment: Hi richard, to clarify. I want to save the contents of a form. My code is roughly based on http://www.sencha.com/learn/the-mvc-application-architecture/ where they are using record.set. Also i'm getting 'form.setValues' is not a function

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this. The code above is fine. My issue was that the my fields names and mappings were incorrect.